# Unable to rename() in php

Tags: php

I've written a code in PHP which moves the file from temp folder to a permanent storage. I should also rename the file too, but I am unable to execute the later one properly. 
The piece of code is as follows:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"previouspapers/".$dept."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$path='http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/';
$path="$path".$dept."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

$path1='http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/12345';

rename($path,$path1);
$fpath=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Please help me to find the mistake.

Comment: Why not move the file directly to the new filename?

Comment: Hi, what exactly goes wrong at which point? Please provide some more information.

Comment: On rename you must use full path `C:/images/...` not `http:// ....`

Comment: [`rename()` is not supported on the `http` wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), you can however send `DELETE`'s and `PUT`'s with [context settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Comment: Do the directories called http:, 127.0.0.1, example, and so on, exist?

Comment: Yeah they do, and even the file uploads too, but rename() returns error, rest all is good @joni

Comment: I dint get you @MikeW. My intention is, when a file is uploaded(say it resume.pdf) the file before being stored, it should be renamed with the username(say 12345).

Comment: `rename('http://google.com', 'http://bing.com');` woohoo!

Comment: @RamaReddy Your code moves the uploaded file into the file store and then promtly tries to rename it. Use the new filename as the target name in `move_uploaded_file()`. Then there's no need to rename the file.

Answer (score 3):

`rename` renames files and folders, not HTTP URLs. You cannot rename

```
"http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/$dept/$_FILES[file]"
```

to

```
'http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/12345
```

You should rename

```
"previouspapers/$dept/$_FILES[file]"
```

to

```
"previouspapers/12345"
```

instead; because, as your call to `move_uploaded_file` suggests, your working directory is `examples`.

Comment: Yup, then what should i do to rename it?(eg: resume.pdf to 12345.pdf)

Comment: Now I am doing like this: $x='example/previouspapers/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]; $y='example/previouspapers/12345'; rename($x,$y); But the same problem!! @oswald

Comment: Relative file names (i.e. the ones without a slash as first character) are interpreted relative to the working directory (find out with [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) if you are interested). Your call to `move_uploaded_file` suggests, that `example` is your current working directory, so you should not specify this path componenent when renaming files.

Answer (score -1):

```
       $path = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/';
       $path .="$path".$dept."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

I'd guess you are not correctly concatenating the path variables. See the .= (NB: np space between them)

Comment: That's ur mistake @cups.
$path='http://127.0.0.1/example/previouspapers/';
$path="$path".$dept."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
This is my code, and I am even executing it